# Cause of stator burn on ER-6F 2009

Tags: battery, battery-charger, kawasaki, stator, rectifier

So yesterday I stopped for gas and when I tried starting the bike again it did not work. After some google-ing I found it was probably the stator. When I opened up the bike the stator had a burn spot. My question is, what might have caused this?
[image]
[image]

In this post ([Kawasaki EX650 - What causes a stator to burn out?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21325/kawasaki-ex650-what-causes-a-stator-to-burn-out)) there was talk about the rectifier being bad. However, I tested it. And I believe it's working as it should.
[image]
[image]

(I did this test for all 3 of the bottom pins getting the same result. When running the tests for the top right pin instead of the top left the results were reversed. Which is good I believe.)

Location of rectifier:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this your rectifier? -https://www.manualslib.com/manual/953658/Kawasaki-Er-6n.html?page=530

Comment: Mine is mounted more to the rear i believe. Above the chain, under the battery (added image to post). Or i just tested the wrong part