# Electric start isn't functioning anymore

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starter, yamaha

The electric start of my motorcycle isn't working anymore. I can hear a buzzing noise. I can still start it using kick start though.

Can it be fixed?

Please help!

Comment: What model and year Yamaha do you have?

Answer (score 4):

There can be two things that are preventing your motorcycle from starting.

- A dead Battery: Check if your Horns,lights and other electrical systems are working when the vehicle is not turned on(do this in the morning before starting your motorcycle) or at least the horn should work.If the intensity of the horn sound dips after a second or two then it's probably your battery, in that case you will have to check for your battery plus dynamo/rectifier with the mechanic or an ammeter.
- Dead Starter motor: Your starter motor might be bust, if it is an old vehicle then there are chances that your starter motor might be dead or needs servicing.

Answer (score 2):

**It sounds like your battery is going bad**

The buzzing or rapid clicking sound you hear is your starter solenoid.  When you hit the start button on your handlebar it sends voltage to your solenoid.  The solenoid has a small electromagnet that flips a switch to send battery power to your starter.  If the solenoid is buzzing then that would mean that your battery is not holding a strong enough charge to keep the solenoid powered enough to maintain contact for the starter circuit.

**Possible Issues**

The issues you may be experience include:

- Battery won't hold a charge, it's bad and needs replacement
- Stator issues.  You might have a bad stator that isn't generating any power.
- Rectifier.  You have rectifier/voltage regulator that isn't charging the battery and is bad.  As well, it might not be converting the generated power from your stator to DC current from AC

If I had to guess and just swap out a part.  I would swap out the battery and see if that rectifies the problem.  If not, come back here and ask how you can test out your system to identify what the root issue is.

Here are some helpful links.

- [How to test a motorcycle charging system](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/12765/9164)
- [How to use a multimeter](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/25816/9164)

Answer (score 0):

I think, that starter motor, but firstly You should check the voltage on power connections on starter, when the start button is turned ON. Secondly, try to clean all connection around starter, a "+" connection and the ground. If it's doesn't help, plug out starter, unscrew, pull out and look inside, maybe electric brushes are over. One more thinks.. if the voltage on connections will be zero find and check relay!
Best!

Answer (score 0):

I Have just sorted a problem with my Zonte Tiger 50cc starter was clicking not turning engine over. I had a fully charged new battery had starter motor out and cleaned it the bike is only 2 years old.
After thinking again I removed flywheel cover and found a lot of rubbish inside so cleaned all around with WD40 and removed spark plug the engine turned over lovely. This for info for anyone whol has starter problems with engine not turning so dont just think it;s the starter motor.